# Getting Number Of Downloads Of Android and IOS and Distinct Unique Users

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am using the below query to get the number of downloads for IOS and Android using Firebase,

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)
    , app_info.firebase_app_id
FROM
    `xxx.analytics_xxx.events_*`
WHERE
    event_name = "first_open" 
    AND (app_info.firebase_app_id = "1:xxx:android:xxx" OR app_info.firebase_app_id = "1:xxx:ios:xxxx")
GROUP BY app_info.firebase_app_id
```

If I remove `event_name = "first_open"` then the count is difference (around 200-300). So, why distinct unqiue user count is different using first_open and not using first_open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the count is higher when you remove the `WHERE event_name = "first_open"` clause. Your BigQuery export most likely does not contain the `first_open` event for those users. Perhaps the BigQuery export was enabled after the users had already installed and opened the app.

You can try the following simplified query to provide similar results:

```sql
SELECT
    device.operating_system,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS user_count
FROM `xxx.analytics_xxx.events_*`
GROUP BY 1
```